# syntax highlighting in ipython console

Tags: python, ipython

I am using `ipython` both in `qtconsole` and in the terminal

In `ipython-qtconsole`, when I type `import pandas as pd` the words have syntax highlighting.

However, when I type in the console, all text is white.

Is it possible to have syntax highlighting in Python console as well?

My `ipython` versions are:

```
ipython                    1.2.1
ipython-qtconsole          1.2.1
```

Comment: Not in plain IPython. You can use [bipython](http://bipython.org/), a combination of IPython with [bpython](http://bpython-interpreter.org/).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, if you use IPython 5.0 or above, It makes uses of [Python Prompt Toolkit](http://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.org/en/stable/) which does highlight code as you type, as well as support real, and sane multi-line edition.

To upgrade use :

```
pip install  ipython --upgrade
```

This is based on the work of Jonathan Slenders on [ptpython](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ptpython):

```
python -m pip install ptpython
```

which provide 2 commands: `ptpython` and `ptipython` which should syntax highlight in your terminal. `ptipython` is a proof of concept so will likely miss some functionality of IPython, but push the interface a bit further.

Note that jupyter-console, which can connect to IPython as a kernel will also make use of prompt toolkit and highlight code as you type.

Comment: Is this related to `jupyter console`?

Comment: Hum, yes and no. Depending on the sens of your question. SO comments is not the bast place to answer thoug. In short: jupyter-console now use prompt_toolkit as well, but is a 2 process console that connect to Jupyter Kernel, the kernel can be IPython, or Julia, haskell... Due to it's 2 process nature the jupyter console can do thing plain IPython can't, and can't do thing plain IPython can.

Comment: I see, thanks. Hm, on Windows ipython 5.0 still is without colors, while jupyter has them. Is there an additional setting required?

Comment: No, no additional settings. Please open bug report, if you have issues.

Comment: Strange, after the weekend it now also works. Thanks :)

Comment: Great, Happy it works for you. If computer were predictable machines, we would knew by now :-)

Comment: In _theory_ they should - but I'm a Theoretical Physicist and know about reality 

Comment: The difference between theory and practice is that in theory it's the same.

Answer (score 2):

[Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/), `ipython`'s [spin-off](https://ipython.org/#jupyter-and-the-future-of-ipython) for notebooks, provides the command `jupyter console`, which is precisely what you (and I) are looking for.