# ipython: how to put colors like in idle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, anaconda

recently I install anaconda, which have IPython, every time that I try to use the Ipython console always annoy me the lack of color when typing something, like for example

```
In [1]: import itertools

In [2]: print('hello')
hello

In [3]:
```

there is a way to give colors to all key word and build-functions so that in the example above `import` be yellow and `print` be purple like in the idle???

Comment: If you want syntax highlighting, then you could use the Jupyter notebook

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25190889/syntax-highlighting-in-ipython-console

Comment: @cricket_007 to bad, then I will stick with the idle for now

Comment: I'm fairly sure the Jupyter Notebook is installed by anaconda. I haven't used IDLE in forever, but it is very basic.

Comment: @cricket_007 yes it is, but I find it a little weird to my taste, it open in the web browser and don't have a easy way to test the code I wrote, and if it have is not in plain view, so I don't find it user friendly... if anything I will use spyder, but for most of my uses IDLE is perfect. I wanted to starting to use ipython because it have some nice features, but the lack of syntax highlighting is a huge detriment in my book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to open Ipython typing in the terminal

```
 Ipython qtconsole
```

It provides an interface which is much better (by far) than Ipython shell. It takes advantage of PyQt. Source: https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/qtconsole.html

From previous source:

*Terminal IPython has always had some coloring, but never syntax highlighting. There are a few simple color choices, specified by the colors flag or %colors magic:*

- *LightBG for light backgrounds*
- *Linux for dark backgrounds*
- *NoColor for a simple colorless terminal*

*The Qt widget has full support for the colors flag used in the terminal shell.*

*The Qt widget, however, has full syntax highlighting as you type, handled by the pygments library.*

Comment: :O awesome, that look great