# Color-coded syntax in terminal

Tags: python, terminal

currently, the terminal I'm using to write my Python code is monochrome gray on black, but [this](http://tstringer.github.io/vscode/2016/06/06/vscode-terminal.html) and [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal) example show that you can have color coded syntax as well. I can't identify anything in the default settings which indicates an ability to use color coded syntax in the terminal. I'd like to use a terminal window as a Python interactive shell, so color coded text is a must. How do I do so?

Visual Studio 2015 is so much easier in this regard, but I suppose that is because VSCode isn't an IDE. I just really like having an interactive shell to work with as I test new script.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/1011482/changing-colors-of-the-powershell-prompt-in-windows-10. And I don't think you can syntax-highlight Python unless the REPL colors it for you.

Comment: Have you taken a look at your second example? Nothing in there shows color-coded user input.

Answer (score 9):

The default console REPL does not have syntax highlighting. However The IDLE IDE that ships with CPython has a syntax-highlighting REPL (interactive shell).

[IPython 5](https://ipython.org/install.html) also has [syntax highlighting in REPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25190889/syntax-highlighting-in-ipython-console):

[image: IPython screenshot]
<sub>(source: [jupyter.org](https://blog.jupyter.org/content/images/2016/07/Screen-Shot-2016-07-07-at-11-28-25-1.png))</sub>

Comment: I want that, but inside the integrated terminal panel in VS Code. Is it possible? I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: @haz IPython 5 is a terminal program! Also PyCharm IDE from JetBrains is a full-featured IDE with syntax highlighting, and can run the IPython in a terminal pane with full color; the Community edition is free to use.

Comment: IPython 5 works beautifully, and I will give PyCharm a try. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks to you I learned that I already had ipython3 installed with the exact same version of python (3.9.2) as my regular python3 command! I was just using the worse command to open my Python shell.